# Quando devemos declarar um método como estático?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, algoritmo, método

Como regra geral é considerada má pratica de programação usar métodos estáticos. Mas em que situações ela se justifica (ou não se justifica)?

---

**Por exemplo**: se eu fosse criar um método simples para ler um arquivo de texto:

Criando esse método no tipo de instância eu teria que instanciar a classe apenas para poder executá-lo, o que não faz muito sentido (código em portugol):

```
variavel texto = novo Arquivo().lerArquivo('C:/arquivo.txt')
```

Já na forma estática eu chamaria o método diretamente:

```
variavel texto = Arquivo.lerArquivo('C:/arquivo.txt')
```

Comment: Uma bom exemplo de uso de `método` estático é o padrão `Singleton`. Esse padrão possui um construtor `privado` que é instanciado pelo próprio método estático da class e garante que uma e apenas uma instância de determinado objeto exista na execução da aplicação.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Por definição, um atributo ou método estático é aquele que não requer uma instância para ser utilizado.

Isso quer dizer que um método estático, como no seu exemplo, pode ser executado livremente sem a necessidade de instanciação de um objeto. Entretanto, devido à sua forte ligação com à classe (uma vez que é declarado no escopo dela) isso quer dizer que seu uso requer *a menção* à essa sua origem, e por isso a classe serve como forma de organização de *funções de uso mais geral*.

Por isso, a criação de métodos (ou atributos) estáticos é interessante quando se intenciona que eles sejam de livre utilização, mas bem identificados por um contexto representado pela classe.

Exemplos clássicos são as funções matemáticas como seno, cosseno, raíz quadrada, etc, ou as constantes como PI, E, etc. Muitas linguagens implementam essas funções de forma estática em uma classe específica para elementos matemáticos, permitindo fazer, por exemplo:

```java
float valor = Math.sin(Math.PI);
```

O método para o cálculo do seno (`Math.sin`) é geral porque calcula o valor do seno dado apenas o ângulo em radianos recebido como parâmetro. Por isso, não requer uma instância de objeto e faz sentido ser criado de forma estática. Sua inclusão na classe de matemática (`Math`) juntamente com outros métodos e atributos contantes (como o `Math.PI`) permite organizar essas implementações em um mesmo contexto significativo (isto é, de matemática) para o desenvolvedor que for utilizá-las.

No seu exemplo, você pode considerar esse aspecto de generalidade do que deseja alcançar com a implementação ao decidir por criar o método como estático ou não:

- Se deseja apenas ler o arquivo e retornar o conteúdo no formato textual, muito provavelmente um método estático seja suficiente. Especialmente se existirão outras funcionalidades que também terão esse caráter e farão sentido em ser agrupadas na mesma classe.
- Por outro lado, se essa implementação pode vir a fazer uso de estados ou informações previamente processados ou pode ela mesmo produzir algo que persista para execuções futuras, parece natural que uma instância seja necessária para no mínimo armazenar essas informações e estados.

*P.S.: Aliás, eu acho que qualquer recurso existente em uma linguagem de programação pode ser usado de maneira incorreta a ponto de se tornar uma "má prática". Isso não quer dizer que a utilização do recurso seja sempre inapropriada.*

Answer (score 11):

Não são os métodos estáticos que são má prática, mas sim o uso que se faz deles. Usar métodos estáticos em um código qualquer, torna esse código mais acoplado, pois os métodos estáticos não podem ser substituídos.

Mas será que isso é ruim?

Depende...

### Quando é bom ou ruim?

- Se for um código de altíssima performance, que tem que tirar proveito de cada ciclo de processamento, então isso é ótimo: menos abstração, o compilador pode copiar o conteúdo do método para o local da chamada (inline)... tudo de bom para performance.
- Se o código for um que não precisa ter tanta performance assim, você pode tirar mais benefício de abstrações, tornando o código mais testável... tudo de bom para a manutenção do sistema.

Mas mesmo no segundo caso, métodos estáticos possuem seu lugar. Mas acho que esses métodos devem ser chamados, por implementações de serviços.

**Exemplo:**

No .Net, existe a classe `DateTime` (na verdade é uma struct), que possui métodos estáticos para várias coisas.

Quando quero que um código seja testável, ao invés de usar, por exemplo `DateTime.Now()`, eu prefiro fazer um serviço chamado `DateTimeService`, que implementa a interface `IDateTimeService` e que em sua implementação chama os métodos estáticos.

Isso me dá a opção de fazer uma outra implementação de `IDateTimeService` que me permite injetar uma data qualquer como se fosse o valor de `Now()`... ou seja, eu abstraio a classe estática na forma de serviço, para casos em que testar é mais importante que performance.

**Analisando o seu caso:**

No caso da leitura de arquivos, eu faria com que existisse uma implementação principal que é a que de fato lê um arquivo, de forma estática, e quando precisasse usar esse método, eu usaria uma abstração que por sua vez iria chamar o método estático.

**Motivo:** ler arquivos não é uma tarefa que requer altíssima performance, portanto cai no segundo caso que apontei acima.

Answer (score 5):

#### Método estático na orientação a objetos

O problema do método estático é o acoplamento, pois você está utilizando uma classe específica em vez de injetá-la como dependência. Esse é o motivo de o exagero em código estático ser considerado uma má prática por muitos.

Quem for utilizar sua classe que contém o método estático vai estar acoplado a ela. Claro que existem contextos onde você não vai precisar trocar de implementação, porém é preciso estar consciente em relação a métodos estáticos e seu uso.