# É uma má prática usar apenas métodos estáticos numa classe?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, métodos-estáticos

Estava estudando mais afundo o OOP, aprendendo conceitos mais avançados como Polimorfismo, Override, Classes e métodos finais, abstração, namespace e etc...

Eu aprendi sobre os métodos estáticos, onde ela não pode ser acessada pelo objeto (operador `$this`), e obviamente não pode ser instanciada pelo objeto usando o operador `->`, mas eu estava olhando alguns projetos no GitHub e vi que alguns deles, usavam todos métodos estáticos, tudo na classe era estática, desde seus atributos até seus métodos privados e protegido, o cara usou do operador `self::` pra poder referenciar e usar os métodos da classe e seus atributos, aí caso você quisesse utilizar a classe, era só usar o `namespace` dela, algo como `use class\ProjetoDoCara;` e chamar o único método público que faz todo o serviço `ProjetoDoCara::Operar();`.

Mas aí me surgiu uma dúvida, se isso é uma boa prática, isso não foge das regras da `OOP`?

Comment: Essa é minha opnião. A alma das boas práticas em programação, independente da linguagem e tem três pontos fundamentais que são a Legibilidade do código, o ganho de produtividade e a reutilização do código, de maneira fácil, por outro pessoa. Não considero o caso que você sitou como uma má prática, uma vez que, a instanciação de uma classe especifica não tenha tanta relevancia no projeto.

Comment: Tem quem use apenas para não criar um objeto(praticidade), muitos métodos ou atributos estáticos podem ser sintomas [desse problema](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90047/91).

Comment: Relacionados: [Quando devemos declarar um método como estático?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12651/3117) e [Qual a função de um método estático?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/3117)

Comment: Eu ia fazer essa pergunta hoje, mas pesquisando em uma série de artigos entendi melhor *"quando devemos usar"*, o que vai da necessidade de cada um no Design do projeto da classe especifica. Talvez eu tente postar algo depois.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boa tarde, Cassiano José!

Utilizar muitas variáveis estáticas é uma má prática sim. Alguns podem defender que em alguns casos específicos seja algo usável, mas de forma geral, comece fugindo um pouco das variáveis estáticas.

Um dos exemplos que se pode utilizar variáveis estáticas é para quando ela for uma variável final, que não terá mais o seu valor alterado.

Pensa no seguinte caso: Você publica uma aplicação .net na web(Irei falar apenas de .net, mas imagino que se aplique para diversas outras plataformas), e então você coloca um determinado objeto como estático, vamos utilizar como exemplo um Produto. O usuário 1, popula este objeto após selecionar um Produto para alguma determinada operação. O usuário 2 vai lá e popula este mesmo objeto para fazer uma outra(ou a mesma) operação. Pronto, temos um conflito. O usuário 1 terá um objeto Produto com as informações que o usuário 2 setou neste objeto.

Recentemente peguei um projeto que estava ocorrendo este tipo de conflito, minha solução mais simples e funcional, imagino, foi gerar uma Sessão com as informações que anteriormente estavam indo para um objeto estático. A Sessão é única, então cada usuário tinha lá a sua sessão armazenada podendo passar as informações para uma outra página do sistema, por exemplo.

Então, é isso aí, muito cuidado com as variáveis estáticas.

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraços.

Comment: é, olhando por este lado realmente fica complicado um projeto que tenha classes totalmente com métodos estáticos, numa ocasião como esta que você citou, realmente afetaria e muito o sistema! obrigado pela observação!

Comment: Nesse exemplo citado, de conflito por dois usuários, não ocorre no php, por exemplo. Pois cada requisição é uma instância indepdendente. Também não deveria ocorrer em linguagens de ambiente similar (web)..

Comment: Hm, legal Daniel, não sabia que no Php isto não ocorria, interessante.

Answer (score 15):

Resolvi responder porque as respostas atuais não falam sobre PHP que é a pergunta, e a aceita fala sobre variáveis e não métodos, vai entender o AP.

## Boa prática

Primeiro começo pelo que sempre digo: esse negócio de boa ou má prática é um jeito simplificado que as pessoas inventaram para dar (pra não usar uma palavra mais contundente, mas quem está antenado, sabe do que estou falando) regras que nem elas mesmas sabem bem porque estão falando. Tem que fazer o certo em cada situação. Por isso é preciso entender os fundamentos e parar de procurar receitas de bolo. Isso não funciona bem.

## OOP

Se é pra falar em boa prática porque não se perguntar se [usar OOP em PHP é uma boa prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101). Lá eu dou vários motivos e espero que eles sejam suficientes para não parecer pura receita de bolo.

De fato classes estáticas não conformam muito com OOP. Mas e daí? Pra que fazer OOP? Tem que justificar para adotar qualquer coisa? Usar por usar não é um motivo. Se o problema não pede OOP para ser bem resolvido, não precisa seguir isto.

Se vai ter apenas métodos estáticos, porque não usar funções comuns? Existe algum motivo para criar uma classe? Sempre se questione. E lembre-se que está usando PHP, a aplicação roda em pedaços curtos por muito pouco tempo. Complicar demais o *design* traz um *overhead* desnecessário que pode fazer um enorme diferença nesse modelo de execução.

Mas se o fizer, não tem nada de errado, só acho desnecessário. Ninguém consegue citar um problema real e que não tenha solução que isso possa causar. Claro que se o problema pede uma instância, aí é outra coisa, mas aí está usando a ferramenta errada para o problema. Isso é outra coisa.

Alguns dos problemas relatados nas outras respostas simplesmente não acontecem em PHP, ou só acontecem se a pessoa não souber o que está fazendo. Alguns sequer fazem sentido. Algumas respostas dizem que é problemático, mas não diz porque é, como é típico de quem adora "boas práticas".

## Estado estático

Ter [estado em uma classe estática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101) pode ser um problema, mas em PHP raramente é. Desde que não abuse, se souber o que está fazendo. Vou repetir porque muita gente acha que PHP é .NET, C++, Java, etc. Não é, a execução do PHP é efêmera. É uma linguagem de *script* e ela brilha fazendo isto. É uma pena quando as pessoas tentam impor modelos de outras linguagens para ela. E vale lembrar que ninguém usa *thread* em PHP, mesmo podendo. É raro fazer sentido no tipo de aplicação que PHP lida. E o `include` é seu amigo. Não faça dele um inimigo.

Até existem casos para fazer OOP, existem casos para criar uma classe, existem casos para fazer tudo estático (até sem classes), existem [casos pra Singleton](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/18860/101). As pessoas precisam procurar coisas que simplifiquem suas vidas, não que compliquem.

## Método estático

Só entenda bem [porque usar um método estático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/101) (é outra linguagem, mas a base é a mesma) e [usar uma classe estática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129983/101) (mais geral), [também aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90047/101). Qual a função dele. Saiba que encapsular um método estático tem sua vantagem, mas pode ser que só precise de uma função normal.

## Conclusão

Você pode dizer, "mas você não disse quando usar ou não". Sim, até porque não dá para fazer isso. Sem um caso bem específico eu não sei afirmar se pode usar método estático ou não.

Não vi o projeto citado na pergunta, mas **parece** ser um caso onde método estático era a melhor ferramenta. Se precisava ser uma classe eu não sei, talvez pelo tipo de projeto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

## É uma má prática usar apenas métodos estáticos numa classe?

> Não, não é má prática.

Uma classe completamente estática pode fazer sentido mesmo em um código muito bem organizado.

## Classe completamente estática foge das regras da OOP?

> Classe completamente estática não foge a nenhuma regra da OOP, apenas não se enquadra como OOP.

Veja: OOP implica em falar de objetos, e uma classe completamente estática (que tenha apenas membros estáticos) nunca será um objeto no sentido da OOP.

Mas nada impede você de usar amplamente os conceitos mais importantes da OOP no seu projeto e, eventualmente, quando fizer sentido, utilizar uma classe completamente estática.

Agora, se o código utilizar muito mais classes estáticas do que objetos, dificilmente será enquadrado como um projeto orientado a objetos. Provavelmente estará mais para procedural. Mas nesse caso não quer dizer que ele feriu regras - quer dizer apenas que ele não é OOP.

Answer (score 6):

Não resisti em também ter que postar uma resposta.

> Isso é uma boa prática?

Já foi dito pelo @Maniero que "boa prática" ou "má prática" as vezes é simplesmente uma modinha que todo mundo quer seguir.

Mas primeiramente deveríamos nos perguntar o porquê de usar cada coisa.

Não diria que é uma "boa prática" ou "má prática" usar uma classe cheia de métodos e propriedades estática, mas diria que isso é **um mau uso do recurso**.

Na maioria das vezes, já vi coisas que foram feita com classes estáticas que poderiam ter sido resolvido com a criação de várias funções.

Não costumo seguir algo só porque todo mundo disse que é bom ou ruim, mas gosto de avaliar cada padrão e a necessidade de cada recurso.

Vamos pensar, realmente é necessário criar uma classe, cheia de métodos estáticos, só pra fazer dela um "repositório de funções"?

Se você quiser ser um pouco crítico (como eu sou), vai perceber isso no link do código a seguir.

[illuminate/support/Arr](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Arr.php)

Essa é uma classe da biblioteca `Illuminate\Support`, do Laravel. Ela é chamada de `Arr` porque é uma classe criada para fazer várias operações com `array`.

Se você observar bem essa classe, vai perceber que ela possui cada método estático com a necessidade de passar o `array` como parâmetro para trabalhar com ela.

Eu amo usar o Framework Laravel, mas não preciso concordar com tudo que está lá. Apesar de usar essa classe em algumas partes dos sistemas que desenvolvi, percebo que estruturar uma classe toda estática apenas para trabalhar com `arrays` é fazer mau uso dos método estáticos.

Se você observar bem, poderia ser feita uma função para cada método dessa classe, ao invés de criar uma classe só pra isso.

Outra coisa que eu reparei é que nenhuma propriedade estática é usada, nem sequer para guardar um estado. O que, na minha análise, torna mais inútil ainda uma utilização de uma classe com métodos estáticos para se trabalhar com `arrays`.

O que vou falar agora a seguir não se trata de um padrão, mas apenas minha análise ao desenvolver classes para bibliotecas.

## Vamos aos exemplos

Em se tratando de PHP, não faz sentido termos classes estáticas como essa:

```
  class Util {

       public static function tratarTexto($string) {
              // faz o tratamento

             return $string;
       }
 }
```

Ao invés disso, poderia ser feito algo como:

```
 function tratar_texto($string) {
      // faz o tratamento
       return $string;
 }
```

Mas aí alguém vai dizer:

> Ah, mas eu queria separar as funções dentro de um *namespace* específico, como se faz com as classes. Foi por isso que fiz assim.

No PHP é possível definir `namespaces`, não só pra classes, mas para funções e constantes também.

Então seria perfeitamente possível organizar o seu código de outras formas mais legíveis, como;

```
namespace System\Core;

const MY_CONST_VALUE = 42;

function my_function ($str) {

}
```

O que eu percebo no final de contas é que muita gente faz coisas do tipo (não só encher uma classe de métodos estáticos, mas outras coisas) porque não tem ideia do que está fazendo.

## Então pra quê serve o método estático?

Eu costumo muito observar como a linguagem costuma usar coisas. E a forma que o PHP costuma usar os métodos estáticos é para criação da instância da própria classe, já que a linguagem não possui o recurso de usar múltiplos construtores.

Um exemplo é a classe `DateTime`.

Você pode usá-la assim:

```
$date = new DateTime; // Date(object)
```

E caso precise de inicializada a partir de outras passagens de parâmetros, como no caso de uma interpretação de formato, você pode fazer assim:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '20/08/2009'); // Date(object)
```

Então, eu posso concluir que, umas das finalidades do método estático é o de poder criar uma forma alternativa de instanciação da própria classe.

Outra forma que vejo que é muito comum é na utilização de `factories`, para facilitar a instância de uma determinada classe, dado ao nível de complexidade e dependências da mesma.

Exemplo:

```
// Forma complexa
new Controller(new Response(), new Request())

// Forma simplificada

Controller::factory(); // Os parâmetros Response e Request são passados internamente
```

Lembrando que os método estáticos não se limitam a fazer o que está sendo feito acima, mas no meu ponto de vista, numa estrutura OOP faz mais sentido você usar um método estático para auxiliar nas operações internas da própria classe do que encher uma classe dele só pra ter uma "organização".

Os exemplos acima tem, unicamente, a finalidade de demonstrar que o que importa é a finalidade do recurso. Não estou criando nenhum padrão para ser seguido cegamente, mas apenas tentando demonstrar que em algumas casos há recursos sendo utilizados que costumam deixar algo mais complicado/confuso do que se utilizasse outros.

No final das contas, o que importa mesmo é saber bem qual é a finalidade de cada coisa para não fazer besteira :p

Comment: No PHP, funções tem escopo global, então organizar funções em namespace não vai funcionar.

Comment: Como assim, jovem? Não entendi o seu questionamento @EvertondaRosa

Comment: você escreveu _No PHP é possível definir namespaces, não só pra classes, mas para funções e constantes também._, porém o manual do PHP traz a seguinte informação: _All functions and classes in PHP have the global scope - they can be called outside a function even if they were defined inside and vice versa._ Por isso disse que organizar os funções com `namespace` não vai funcionar, embora, se não me engano, o PHP nbão dispare nenhum erro ou aviso sobre isso.

Comment: @EvertondaRosa você já fez testes? Porque, nos que eu fiz, deu certo. E tem que ver se a documentação foi atualizada, já que desde a versão 5.3 pra cá diversas mudanças foram feitas.

Comment: A algum tempo eu tentei definir funções sobre um namespace e acontecia exatamente como o manual dizia. Eu não lembro em qual versão do PHP era. Hoje, fiz novos testes e o comportamento mudou: funções definidas sob um namespace agora são isoladas das definidas em outros namespaces e no escopo global. Na prática, podemos ter funções com nomes iguais, porém em escopos diferentes (testado com PHP 7.2.2). Não testei a definição de função dentro de função, mas se definir as funções \minhafuncao(); MeuNamespace1\minhafuncao() e MeuNamespace2\minhafuncao(), tudo vai funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

O uso de atributos e métodos estáticos não pode fugir da sua definição em orientação a objetos, caso contrário, será configurada uma má prática, ou seja,  um jeitinho de facilitar uma dada implementação ou um quebra galho.

Na orientação a objetos, a existência de atributos estáticos é voltada a atributos comuns dentre os objetos pertencentes a uma mesma classe na modelagem de um sistema, não causando um efeito colateral sobre a definição do sistema OO. Por exemplo, funcionários de uma mesma categoria tem, ou pelo menos deveriam ter, a mesma porcentagem de aumento ao fim de cada ano, logo cabe existir um único valor para todos os objetos.

Na mesma linha estão os métodos estáticos,  devem atuar sobre interesses comuns na classe. Como você citou que todos os métodos eram estáticos, isso é uma forma de tornar o paradigma de orientação a objetos mais parecido com o imperativo, logo se perde todas as inúmeras vantagens que o desenvolvimento de um sistema orientado a objetos pode proporcionar.

Comment: Excelente colocação Leandro!

Answer (score 0):

Olhando para os conceitos de OOP, sim, classes estáticas ferem a norma e seria melhor utilizar um Singleton para criar uma classe utilitária.

Vou dar um exemplo para ajudar a ver o problema. No meu código em c++ aqui, achei uma variável estática bRun em uma classe que eu uso para criar todas as threads do meu programa. No lugar de terminar com programa com exit(0) ou algo assim, eu coloco bRun pra falso e todas as threads param de rodar, chamando os destrutores e terminando o programa sem vazamento de memória.

Só que ao fazer isso, estou abrindo mão das vantagens da Orientação a Objeto. Eu não posso determinar a ordem de término das threads, não consigo fazer a herança e adicionar um comportamento ao término de cada thread e por ai vai.

Quando você olha um projeto Open Source, especialmente um em C++, pode ser que ele tenha utilizado o recurso de uma classe toda estática porque as variáveis e métodos nesse caso carregam junto com o programa e podem ir para o Stack no lugar de irem para o Heap (o que não é verdade em muitas linguagens). Ou ele preferiu fazer sem orientação a objetos porque ele ainda não conhecia uma boa forma de fazer, iria levar mais tempo pra ele fazer assim.

Só que depois que você aprender a usar Singleton, vai perceber que é um padrão de design prático o bastante para manter as vantages de orientação a objetos mesmo nessas situações e raramente precisaria de fato de um método estático.

Comment: Também pensei nisso @Rodrigo Guiotti, que ele pensou em fazer otimizações, eu até acho mais prático o uso da forma: `Classe::Método();`, sei lá acho mais limpo, só que realmente fere o desenvolvimento em OOP!