# Quando faz sentido ter apenas métodos e atributos estáticos em uma classe?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes, static, métodos-estáticos

Estudando sobre métodos e atributos estáticos em OOP, me deparei com a seguinte questão: porque em alguns códigos temos classes APENAS com atributos e métodos estáticos?

Existe algum padrão de projeto que fale sobre isso? Em quais casos isso é uma prática aconselhável?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Métodos

É uma questão de necessidade. Se você tem apenas funções (outro nome do [método estático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/101)) que executam alguma coisa isoladamente ou em cima de um objeto qualquer que aquela função não precisa ter maior conhecimento, não tem por que colocar essas funções dentro de um objeto que pode ser instanciado. São funções que pegam uma entrada (opcional), fazem um processamento e soltam uma saída (opcional) sem depender de nenhuma informação de um objeto oculto na sua entrada.

Pela pergunta deve entender o motivo de ter métodos estáticos em uma classe normal. Pense que há casos que só eles são necessários. Aí pode optar por criar uma classe normal e deixar criar uma instância sem sentido (até existe motivo para isso, por exemplo no padrão Strategy), mas quase sempre restringir isso é o melhor caminho e colocar um `static` ali resolve essa questão.

Em algumas linguagens essa confusão não ocorre porque elas aceitam funções e outros membros soltos. Por marketing Java veio com essa estória esdrúxula que tudo deveria estar dentro de uma classe para parecer que tudo é orientado a objeto, mesmo que coisas estáticas estão bem longe de serem orientada a objeto. Aí outras linguagens copiaram essa ideia.

## Atributos

Estado (atributo) estático normalmente tenta-se evitar um pouco já que [estado global pode ser problemático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101). Quando tem estado tem uma boa chance de estar fazendo algo errado (mas pra tudo tem exceção). Claro que estado constante não causa nenhum problema.

Usei seu termo, mas [o correto é campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

## Onde é usado

Um dos melhores exemplos são as funções que agem como [utilitárias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90047/101), elas fazem seu trabalho e ponto, não tem mais nada com que se preocupar. E faz todo sentido quando são aplicadas à alguma coisa que não precisa de instância. Tá cheio de coisas assim em códigos de aplicações bem escritas. Em muitos casos é possível evitar repetição de código ou relações complexas entre classes.

Outro bom exemplo é o `Console`. Só existe um console para se comunicar, ele não precisa estado, pra que criar instância para isto? Só porque fica mais OOP? Não, muito obrigado, preciso de um motivo melhor para escolher outra forma.

Outras relacionadas ao ambiente, informações universais e diretamente ao sistema operacional que só existe um, também são bons exemplos.

Funções de cálculo ou conversão de números costumam funcionar melhor como algo isolado, a interação entre os tipos diferentes dificulta colocar isso como instância, fora que incha muito a classe principal. E nunca terá tudo o que precisa. Sempre terão fórmulas novas a serem adicionadas, cada uma com um objetivo diferente. Não faz sentido pôr isso dentro de um `int` e muito menos criar um objeto de um tipo novo só para lidar com uma fórmula que pode ser facilmente aplicada ao objeto original. Pensa bem, ser obrigado criar uma instância de `Math` só para fazer uma potência de dois números simples não relacionados, parece exagero, não?

Há quem goste de usar uma classe estática para fábricas de objetos.

Sem falar na classe principal que obviamente precisa ser única.

## Quando usar

Há quem discorde, mas eu crio sempre uma classe estática até que eu tenha um motivo de não fazê-lo. É verdade que quase sempre tem um motivo para usar uma classe "normal". Se não tem uma real necessidade de uma instância, se não precisa de herança, polimorfismo, pra que complicar?

Algumas pessoas gostam de fazer tudo instância como forma protetiva. Em geral elas ignoram o [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

Há quem diga que elas são ruins porque as pessoas fazem errado. Então é melhor aprenderem fazer certo. Usar a técnica errada porque não sabe usar a técnica certa não é um bom motivo. Não cabe aqui ficar explicando, mas todos os motivos que dizem que uma classe estática é ruim tem solução, pelo menos em algumas linguagens. Ou então a classe estática realmente não é uma boa ideia.

## Padrão de projeto

Claro que isso é um padrão, [padrões estão em todo lugar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16204/101). Mas não é nenhum famoso, catalogado. É possível que alguém tenha dado um nome, mas isso é pouco ou nada relevante. Na verdade, isso não tem a menor importância. Não devemos nos apegar à padrões. Eles devem nos servir e não nós servimos à eles.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).