# É correto utilizar um método estático de uma classe abstrata?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, métodos-estáticos

Durante uma tarefa de trabalho me deparei com a necessidade de utilizar um método de uma classe abstrata para evitar duplicação de código. Nesse caso, me veio um questionamento se é correto utilizar um método de uma classe, que é por definição, apenas um modelo a ser seguido.

Ex:

```py
class Animal:
  class Meta:
    abstract = True

  @staticmethod
  def andar():
    print('Andar')


andar = Animal.andar()
```

É correto, do ponto de vista conceitual, utilizar o método estático da classe abstrata? Obs: O exemplo é apenas uma forma de mostrar o que estou fazendo.

Se isso não for uma boa prática, como devo proceder para não ferir os conceitos da orientação a objetos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O conceito depende da classe, então só dá para afirmar com um caso concreto. O exemplo quis só demonstrar, mas justamente por ser artificial impede de dar uma resposta definitiva. Esse caso parece que não deve fazer isso, mas porque sequer faz sentido ter esse método como estático (até poderia, não sei o caso concreto, então estou especulando isso com base no meu conhecimento prévio sobre o assunto).

Do ponto de vista técnico tudo que dá para fazer é correto, desde que faça sentido naquele momento.

Se quer saber de boas práticas, cai de novo no primeiro parágrafo, só é boa prática se conhecer o caso concreto. O que é bom para uma coisa pode não ser para outra, e se a pessoa tenta universalizar ela acaba cometendo erros tentando acertar já que não dá para aplicar a mesma ação para todos os casos.

Se você quer saber se costuma dar algum problema? Normalmente não, mas pode criar dificuldades.

Algumas pessoas trabalham com algumas teorias. Algumas dizem que nem deveria existir método estático para começo de conversa. [Eu acho que não](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134732/101). Veja mais em [Qual a função de um método estático?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/101). Se você quer seguir estritamente a orientação a objeto, como alguns pregam (não sei qual o objetivo de fazer isso), nem crie este tipo de método.

Precisa entender para que ele serve para saber usar bem. Se é o que precisa então está ok, se faz sentido o método existir para o tipo e não para o objeto, ele deve ser estático.

Ter um código utilitário que serve para outro método delegar a execução para ele e assim [evitar duplicação de código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) é talvez o maior motivo de existir um método estático.

Em alguns casos deveria usar um método privado e não estático para isso, depende da necessidade. Como Python não tem métodos privados de verdade isso é feito só por convenção colocando um `__` antes do nome.

O que de fato faz o método ser estático em Python é não usar um parâmetro `self`. O decorador permite que este método seja chamado de fora da classe usando o nome da classe para acessar, nem sempre quer isso, pode ser seu caso ou não.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Compreendi seu ponto de vista e argumentos.