# Por que eu deveria criar um método estático e não um que poderia instanciar a classe e utilizar esse método?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Eu realmente não vejo diferença nessas duas utilizações de métodos. Alguém poderia ser mais especifico comigo e me informar sobre isso?

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste post pode ser que ajude... http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12651/11404

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um método estático deve ser criado caso faça sentido tê-lo sem ter uma instância do Objeto.

Exemplo simples: em uma classe `Geladeira` você pode ter um método estático `double converterCelsiusFahrenheit(double celsiu)` mesmo que não tenha uma geladeira. Já o método `void adicionarItem(Item item)` está referenciando uma geladeira em específico, por isso não deveria ser estático, já que precisa de uma instância.

Comment: Entendi!!!!!!! Agora faz sentido.