# Chamar método pela classe ou pela instância?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Qual seria o jeito mais correto de chamar um método de outra classe?

É mais correto criar o objeto:

```
private MinhaClasse minhaclasse;
minhaclasse = new MinhaClasse();
```

Para então chamar um método:

```
minhaclasse.meumetodo();
```

Ou simplesmente chamar a partir da classe:

```
MinhaClasse.meumetodo();
```

Qual é mais vantajoso? Qual que é menos custoso e menos difícil para o sistema executar?

Comment: Relacionado [Quando devemos declarar um método como estático?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12651/2541)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private MinhaClasse minhaclasse;
minhaclasse = new MinhaClasse();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/DeclarationMistake.cs).

Esse código não faz sentido, se ele estiver dentro de um método a primeira linha não compila, se estiver fora de um método a segunda linha não compila.

Imagino que esteja falando de um método estático, porque se for de instância a primeira opção é sua única opção.

Para um método estático não importa, ambos funcionam igual.

Porém considera-se um pouco confuso chamar um método estático como se ele fosse de instância, então a segunda opção seria a mais adequada para dar mais legibilidade e evitar que algum erro aconteça tentando acessar uma instância nula em algo que deveria funcionar sempre. Então não é recomendado.

Imagine você chamar um método pela instância que faz algo que você presumirá acontecer com a instância, mas por ser um método estático ocorre de forma global. Vai demorar pra perceber porque não faz o que você espera.

C# optou por nem permitir a primeira opção para evitar a confusão.

Se a sua preocupação é se deveria criar o método como estático ou não, eu sou dos que acham que deve criar sempre um método estático até que seja necessário ser de instância, e muitas vezes é. O mais comum é que os membros de uma classe precisam ser vinculado à instância.

E minha opção pelo método nem é de performance, que ele até é mais rápido, é para evitar expor algo que não é necessário. Se você não depende de nada que está na instância por que fazer aquele método ser de instância? É claro que precisa se questionar o porquê daquilo não ter relação com a instância. Pode ter sido uma decisão equivocada.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nos comentários da resposta aceita: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582560/oop-in-java-android/49582605#49582605  fiz a mesma pergunta, porém, pelo que entendi, o cara recomenda não usar a menos que seja estritamente necessário métodos estáticos, agora estou em uma real dúvida

Comment: Por isso que falei eme opinião, tem quem pense diferente. Tem que prefira a complexidade de gerenciar instância onde não é necessário. Em geral o argumento é facilitar o teste, o que muitas vezes não é feito, pelo menos com aquele código e **uma** instância acaba sendo criada em todo o ciclo de vida da aplicação só porque decidiram errado. Java complica um pouco, mas é possível ter métodos estáticos e testar sem problemas, falta criatividade ou acham que é mais fácil complicar o código real em vez de complicar o teste.

Answer (score 2):

A forma correta depende do método que você for chamar:

- Se o método tiver o modificador `static`, use o nome da classe.
- Se o método **não** tiver o modificador `static`, use a variável com a referência ao objeto.

Não há diferença significativa de desempenho ou de dificuldade em executar. O foco aqui é que cada um deles serve para uma finalidade e depende bastante da forma como você está organizando a sua aplicação.