# Criar muitas classes estáticas impacta na performance do sistema?

Tags: c#, desempenho, estilo-de-codificação, métodos-estáticos

Eu ando criando muitas classes estáticas para facilitar e limpar o código, como por exemplo uma chamada de API do Google Translate.

```
public static class GoogleTranslate
{
    public static string Translate(string word){
        //código de chamada
    }
}
```

Fazendo assim fica muito mais fácil pois é só chamar:

```
GoogleTranslate.Translate("StackOverflow é a melhor universidade do mundo");
```

Eu tenho bastante classes assim para chamar APIS, como isso é visto diante dos profissionais?

Comment: +1 ótimo questionamento. Se não for pedir muito, quem responder levar mais em consideração o conceito, seria legal pra quem é de outras linguagens entender melhor tambem.

Comment: Já que estamos falando de api e métodos estáticos, vou lhe sugerir que venha a ler este artigo.: [`YOU'RE USING HTTPCLIENT WRONG AND IT IS DESTABILIZING YOUR SOFTWARE`](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/), não responde a sua pergunta, mas pode vir a lhe ajudar.

Comment: @TobiasMesquita vou dar uma lida Valeuu

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/287792/101

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sim, fica mais rápido, classes estáticas não precisam instanciar, que tem um custo nada trivial.

Métodos estáticos são como funções normais de qualquer linguagem, está lá pronto para uso. A vantagem é que ela tem um sobrenome (é praticamente um *namespace*), então organiza melhor o código. Não precisa alocar nada (classe normal há alocação mesmo sem ter estado), não tem mecanismos sofisticados (exceto quando tem estado, mas em geral [não deve usar estado global](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101)). Em classes estáticas todos os métodos devem ser estáticos.

Parece algo muito diferente, mas todas as linguagens que não tentaram se vender como 100% orientada a objeto, que é uma falácia, sempre tiveram, sempre foi útil e deu certo.

O ganho é mais pelo método estático do que pela classe. Vale também para os métodos estáticos de classes quem podem ser instanciadas.

Existem outras características de classes estáticas, mas não são relevantes e muitas vezes até ruins.

Uma delas é a sua construção. Ela ocorre em algum momento antes de ser necessária (pode não ser na carga, mas pode ser, por isso uma técnica de *lazy loading* pode ser interessante). Precisa certificar-se que a forma codificada atende tudo de forma boa, que não exagera na carga do sistema (raramente ocorre), é preciso entender todas as implicações para usar corretamente. Idealmente não deve ter uma construção, mas pode se for necessário, útil e souber o que está fazendo.

Quem gosta de OOP diz que não deve usar, eu venho de uma escola mais pragmática que faz o que deve fazer.

É mais difícil testar, mas não impossível. Eu prefiro dificultar o teste do que dificultar o código principal para facilitar o teste.

Se um dia precisar mudar a estratégia dinamicamente pode se tornar um problema, que é a mesma questão do teste. Se não é algo universal e único a instância pode ser uma opção melhor.

Cuidado com estado global variável na classe estática ou normal. Isso funciona bem em raros casos e precisa saber o que está fazendo. Não crie uma classe estática quando o adequado é uma instância. Se tem estado que potencialmente varia a cada execução, crie uma instância.

Eu e o Stack Overflow abusamos de classes estáticas :) Muitos dizem que isso é um erro terrível, mesmo eles não sabendo do nosso contexto. Quando tem que ser uma instância, eu o faço. Na maior parte das vezes se um dia eu precisar mudar, eu refatoro (eu posso fazer isso, nem todo mundo pode), mesmo nos casos que dão trabalho refatorar, costuma compensar pelo ganho porque em quase todos os casos eu nunca precisei refatorar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Simples assim? Sem nenhuma desvantagem? :o

Comment: Imaginei que seria mais prejudicial do que benéfico :o.

Comment: Nem por o exemplo o facto de que as classes estáticas sao instanciadas pelo *runtime* e que possuam construtores estáticos que podem ter código não trivial neles, criando assim uma inialização mais lenta do sistema?

Comment: @Maniero como sempre trazendo respostas fodas e demonstrando um pouco de sua experiência. Valeu ! (sei que é contra as regras agradecer, mas não consigo não fazer).

Comment: @Omni respondido agora?

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti não é contra as regras, não é necessário, não é positivo, mas também não é negativo demais.

Comment: sempre achei que tivesse sérias desvantagens..obrigado @Maniero por esclarecer vários pontos.

Comment: Um ponto muito interessante é o que você falou do teste... as vezes vemos códigos muito difíceis de entender e dar manutenção.. porém os testes são muito simples.. ou seja.. gasta-se mais tempo com testes ou desenvolvimento? bom ponto.

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro é o que eu falo e muita gente não entende. E pior, muitas vezes o teste é feito burocraticamente, não testa nada útil e deixa de testar o que precisa. Aí a pessoa acha que sou contra testes. Sou contra testes sem sentido. Sou contra piorar o código para facilitar o teste. Nem é questão de tempo gasto, é de complexidade. Claro que qualquer coisa é ruim se feita do jeito errado.

Comment: @Maniero perfeito, entendo que temos que seguir padrões, prinícios(SOLID) por exemplo, e por aí vai.. mas vai exatamente no ponto que você disse.. a partir do ponto que você começa a complicar seu código pra testar algo.. e no fim é algo que não faz sentido, for what? :)

Comment: @Maniero É diferente do Java, né? Que tem o `ClassLoader` que instancia a classe estática do mesmo jeito (só muda o momento de alocação, que é mais no início da execução da aplicação). Então presumo que no Java não é tão vantagem assim usar classes estáticas.

Comment: @Piovezan imagino que sim. C# 9 deve ter uma forma de configurar quando acontece o processo, porque perceberam que há custos em deixar para acontecer mais tarde e a maioria das pessoas não precisa disso, então obrigando inicializar no *startup*, ficaria mais barato.